# If value exist in table dont insert and return its id, else insert and return scope identity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a sql query to insert record if it doesn't exist & returns it's scope identity.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT email from tableUser
where email='a@b.com')
INSERT INTO tableUser (name, countryCode, mobile, email, ip)
VALUES ('name', 91, 9811223344, 'a@b.com', 1)  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

but if record exists then i wanted to return it's ID.

Note : ID is Identity column in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `MERGE` with an `OUTPUT` clause. Something like:

```
MERGE INTO tableUser t
USING (VALUES('name',91,'9811223344','a@b.com',1)) s(name, countryCode, mobile, email, ip)
ON t.email = s.email
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name, countryCode, mobile, email, ip) 
                     values(s.name,s.countryCode,s.mobile,s.email,s.ip)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE set ip = t.ip /* No change */
OUTPUT inserted.ID;
```

(Note that I've also changed mobile to be textual - despite mobile numbers being composed of digits, we don't do maths with them, and often e.g. leading zeros can be important, so it's usually better to not store them as actual numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Try it below query :

```
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT email from tableUser where email='a@b.com')
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO tableUser (name, countryCode, mobile, email, ip)
       VALUES ('name', 91, 9811223344, 'a@b.com', 1)  

       SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   END
   ELSE 
   BEGIN

      SELECT Id FROM tableUser where email='a@b.com'

   END
```

Comment: Thanks, but what you have suggested is a stored procedure. 
Is it possible to perform it using simple query only?